# C# : File rename using ASP:NET MVC and IISExpress

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, file-io

I have a utility to rename a file in a specified directory using a certain condition. Running the code using a console application works well and the file is renamed appropriately. However, when I attempt the same in a web application the file is not getting renamed. I am using VS2017 Development Server for the web application debugging.

What am I missing?

Using the console application code as below the file successfully gets renamed :

Rename method:

```
public static string AddSuffix(string filename, string suffix)
{
    string fDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
    string fName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
    string fExt = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    string renamedFilePath = Path.Combine(fDir, String.Concat(fName, suffix, fExt));
    return renamedFilePath;
}
```

Usage in main program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string batchperiod = "_70_";
    string realPath = @"C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\Solution\Project\BatchIn";
    IEnumerable<string> fileList = Directory.EnumerateFiles(realPath);

    var CurrentBatchName = (from file in fileList
                            let fileName = Path.GetFileName(file)
                            where fileName.Contains(batchperiod)
                            select fileName).FirstOrDefault();

    string absolutePath = (@"C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\Solution\Project\BatchIn\" + CurrentBatchName);
    string newPath = Helpers.AddSuffix(absolutePath, String.Format("({0})", Helpers.parameters.IsProcessed));

    System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(absolutePath);

    if (fi.Exists)
    {
        fi.MoveTo(newPath);
    }
}
```

With this code the file is successfully renamed from

```
GL_Export_70_201907081058.xml
```

to

```
GL_Export_70_201907081058(P).xml
```

The only difference using web application is that the `absolutePath` is stored in a Session variable .. its derived from a preceding operation/ActionResult :

```
var absolutePath = (@"C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\Solution\Project\BatchIn\" + CurrentBatchName);
files.FileName = CurrentBatchName;
Session["AbsoluteBatchPath"] = absolutePath;
```

and later invoked in another ActionResult as :

```
var sourceFile = Convert.ToString(Session["AbsoluteBatchPath"]);
string newPath = AddSuffix(sourceFile, String.Format("({0})", parameters.IsProcessed));
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(sourceFile);

if (fi.Exists)
{
    // Move file with a new name. Hence renamed. 
    fi.MoveTo(newPath);
}
```

What am I missing?

I do suspect there are some permissions I may need to configure when attempting the rename using the Visual Studio Development Server.

Comment: Are you getting any error from web app? This looks like permission related issue, check the permissions on folder for the user with with which you are running the web app.

Answer (score 0):

Your code see perfect there is no missing ,debug and check whether in MVC your code entered fi.exist if condition..

Please confirmed the same